# How to make timeout(1) behave in cron like it behaves in interactive shell

Tags: cron, shell, process, coreutils

Running this command in an interactive bash:

```
$ timeout 1 sleep 2; echo $?
124
```

returns *124* after 1 second, as expected and as documented in timeout(1).

However, if I run the same as a cron job, or if I give that as a command string to bash, it does not:

```
$ bash -c "timeout 1 sleep 2; echo $?"
0
```

Adding `-i` to the bash invocation does not help, neither does using the `--foreground` parameter to timeout(1). I also tried the same with ksh and zsh, but always get the same result, so I guess it must be something inherent to the way timeout(1) works.

I searched the net a bit and found, that it could have to do with how the signalling proceeds through the process groups, but I could not find a solution how to make timeout work as expected in the non-interactive case.

Any hints on how I could achieve that? Ultimately what I want is to run a command in cron that is likely to block forever and I want to detect that case reliably.

Comment: I think that your problem is more in printing the timeout  exit code rather than `timeout` not working in a cron invocation. -  For example `bash -c "exitcode=$(timeout 1 sleep 2 ; echo $?);  echo $exitcode"` should work as you intend. -  -  In general though when your batch job needs to do anything slightly more complicated than simply run on a particular schedule, don't try to run it directly from cron but write a simple shell script wrapper and call that from cron.

Comment: For me that command does not output anything. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the double quotes, `$?` is being expanded *before* the bash command is invoked. It is being replaced by the exit status of the *previous* command (which was the first `exit $?`)

A quick demo

```bash
bash -c 'exit 42'
bash -c "timeout 1 sleep 2; echo $?"   # => 42
```

The solution is to use **single quotes** so that the current interactive bash process does not expand the variable

```bash
bash -c 'timeout 1 sleep 2; echo $?'   # => 124
```

Comment: That's quit a stupid mistake from my side. Thanks for pointing this out. I will check my cronjob script and see if it has the same mistake and post an update to this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the command like this:

```
bash -c "timeout 1 sleep 2"; echo $?
```

Comment: That looks better. Can you explain that different behaviour?

Comment: FOr me it seems like echo print the error code of `timeout`, not `sleep`. But I am not sure :)

Comment: @SebastianStark, or maybe because `bash -c` IMHO run in subshell and ...